# Difference between "not have a minute to call your own" and "rushed​ off your feet"

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms '***not have a minute to call your own***' and '***rushed​ off your feet***'? The definitions in the Macmillan Dictionary are:

- not have a minute to call your own: to be extremely busy
- rushed​ off your feet: very busy

Comment: Do you know the literal meaning of the phrases? I suggest you start with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many casual, idiomatic ways to say "I'm busy".  These are two of them.

One focuses on the fact that when you are busy you don't have free time.

The other focuses on the fact that when you are busy you often need to go quickly to many places.  If you are busy in a way that requires you to sit in one place, you would not say "I'm rushed off my feet".

Comment: I an imagine being 'rushed off my feet' while sitting at a desk, in fact I have often heard  people use the expression that way.